# rhel - file modification logs

Tags: files, rhel, logs

I found a strange file in my `/home/user` named `FireZeMissiles1111.tmp`. I am the sole user and did not create it, so it is kind of suspicious. It may have been left there by a program who's programmer had a sense of humor, but I would like to check it's origin. The last modification time stamp points 5 months in the past, permissions are set to me and my group, I am running RHEL 6.7. Is there any way I could get some meaningful data from the logs ? `ausearch` returned blank, but that is probably due to the time period.

Comment: did you run some sample code from stackoverflow 5 months ago?  the only hit from a google search for `"FireZeMissiles1111.tmp"` is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660205/start-java-program-only-if-not-already-running.   BTW, if you find other suspicious files, a useful first step is to google them (with quotes around the filename in the google search field).

Comment: Yes, I tried googling the file and found the thread. But I have not used that snippet. It is a company owned ntb and I get my updates pushed, so that may be an origin possibility. But now I am more curious about log review capabilities on Linux. This brought it up and I found my self completely in the dark.